# not able to get correct file path for subfolder file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

in this I am trying to load all the excel data from specified folderpath and its subfolder present inside it to sql server... Problem is I am able to read the main folder and subfolder, but while taking the data from sub folder file it taking the path of main folder for that sub folder file

example: file path - d:\test
sub directory : d:\test\test2

inside subdirectory my file is present but when iterating it is reading the path of sub directory file as : d:\test\file_name

please help in this

````
            ```DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@FolderPath);
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);```
````

Comment: I've read your question several times but I really can't understand what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: sure...basically I am trying to load all excel sheets to sql server from a specified folder... and that folder might contain and addition subfolders too.. so when I am trying to load the files from the target folder I am not able to read the subfolder files

Comment: Why aren't you able to read the subfolder files?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Directory structure:
// C:\Temp\ExcelFiles\Excel1.xlsx
// C:\Temp\ExcelFiles\SubFolder\Excel2.xlsx
var path = @"C:\Temp\ExcelFiles";
var allExcelFilesInPathAndSubFolders = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This approach returns the expected 2 Excel file names as string array (i.e. `C:\Temp\ExcelFiles\Excel1.xlsx` and `C:\Temp\ExcelFiles\SubFolder\Excel2.xlsx`).

The approach in your post returns an array of FileInfo. You can get all relevant information from that; the name with or without path, the file extension, and using `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` you can get the name without extension.

```
// Directory structure:
// C:\Temp\ExcelFiles\Excel1.xlsx
// C:\Temp\ExcelFiles\SubFolder\Excel2.xlsx
var path = @"C:\Temp\ExcelFiles";
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

// Excel1.xlsx
var firstFileName = files.First().Name;

// Excel1
var firstFileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files.First().Name);

// .xlsx
var fileFileExtension = files.First().Extension;

// C:\Temp\ExcelFiles\Excel1.xlsx
var firstFileFullName = files.First().FullName;
```

Comment: I am using FileInfo[] class too with the directory, and it will be a string vairable to hold all the files of all the directories and sub directories

Comment: [Files returned by OP's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1mjL.png) vs [Files returned by your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgMNm.png)

Comment: @Llama how can it be used with fileInfo[] ??

Comment: @hatim You've not really specified what issue you're facing. The code you're using will return all of the matching files in the directory you pass and subdirectories.

Comment: @Llama I guess I simply do not understand the question then.

Comment: @DeMaki No, nor do I. OP hasn't provided enough information for us to understand the question.

Comment: @hatim I suggest you edit your question to include this line from that code: `fileFullPath = FolderPath + "\\" + file.Name;`. Without it, your question gives no indication of what issue you might have. Anyway, you should be using `file.FullName`, which includes the path. `File.Name` only gives you like `Excel1.xlsx`.